# With Rails 5, what is the most efficient way to generate and use a Basecamp-style "hash_id" (instead of sequential row id's) for each new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, url, activerecord

What I'm going for is URL's very similar to [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/)'s:

```
https://3.basecamp.com/4000818/buckets/7452203/message_boards/1039416768
```

I have already achieved this functionality by following [this guide](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-hash-ids-in-your-url-in-ruby-on-rails-5-e8b7cdd31733), but I am unsatisfied with the process of needing to run potentially millions of .exists? lookups to find an open number and fear this will very quickly hamper performance of my app.

```
def set_hash_id
    hash_id = nil
    loop do
      hash_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(9).gsub(/-|_/,('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)])
      break unless self.class.name.constantize.where(:hash_id => hash_id).exists?
    end
    self.hash_id = hash_id
  end
```

I find it hard to believe that Basecamp is relying on something so inefficient on every record save and I'm looking to find out how they do it or to find a setup that will look the same but without the overhead of the linked tutorial.

I'd appreciate any input on methods to generate a non-sequential record ID. I am not interested in UUID's as I can't stand the non-pleasing URL's they generate. Also, they must be integers. Basically, exactly like the Basecamp URL but without the overhead of the exists? checks. Is it possible they are doing some kind of combination of numbers with an encoded timestamp or something to ensure there is no collisions? I have explored the [hashids.org](http://www.hashids.org/ruby/) method but this does not generate integer-only hashes.

I am using Postgres as my database, in case this is helpful.

Comment: It seems rather unlikely that you would need to run through *millions* of `.exists?` to find a unique number. How many existing numbers would there need to be for the given approach to create performance issues? How many digits would you need an identifier to be in order for the given approach *not* to create performance issues?

Comment: Just project the highest number of records you can foresee in the most optimistic scenario, and use integers that will provide you 2 or 3 orders of magnitude headroom. This will make single collisions unlikely and more than one collision extremely unlikely.

Comment: @jvillian i agree millions is a bit outlandish but lets say there are millions of records already and here is my method of generating the hash_id: hash_id = Array.new(8) { rand(10) }.join , i can imagine it spitting out plenty of numbers that have been used already and if every lookup takes a 1-2 milliseconds, the delay on the user end could be very long.

Comment: @moveson , any concern with my method of generating the hash (shown in above comment)?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Or you could just generate a single random number and ensure consistent number of digits by filling any empty spaces with zeros: `rand(100_000_000_000).to_s.rjust(11, '0')`

Comment: If you have an algorithm that generates potentially 100_000_000_000 options  (as @moveson suggests) and you have 10_000_000 existing records, what is the probability that you will pull an already-existing number in one iteration? Two? Three? How many iterations before p is functionally zero?

Comment: Why not use Optimus? There are [PHP](https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus) and [Go](https://github.com/pjebs/optimus-go) implementations to work from.

Comment: The likelihood of a collision if you use a random number with 9 digits is so low that you probably won't see it in your lifetime. And even if there is a collision it'll get lost in your error messages and you won't even know it, because your code should be able to handle this kind of errors gracefully. Just use: `SecureRandom.random_number(100_000_000)` if you need consistent width add some zero padding. Oh, and forget the repeated key check, its not worth it in this case.

Comment: Optimize for reading: Generate `x` random numbers upfront and store them in a database table. When you actually need a number just pick the next random number from that table and mark it as used. If there are only `y` unused random numbers left in the table start a background job that fills the table up with new numbers. Close `x` and `y` wisely depending on how many numbers you usually need on a daily base...

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency-wise I think you should be fine. [GitLab also uses something similar](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable.rb#L12-15) for unique token generation.

There's another issue though that's worth considering:

Your method does not guarantee to generate a unique key, as the operation is not atomic (neither is GitLab's). Between checking for uniqueness and writing the record to the database the same key *could* have been generated.

You have at least 2 options to handle this. Both solution should also be more efficient (which is your main concern).

### Catch the DB's unique key constrain violation on save

```
def save
  begin
    self.hash_id = generate_hash_id
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
    # 1. you may need to check the message for the specific constraint
    # 2. you may need to implement an abort condition to prevent infinite retries
    retry
  end
end
```

You could can also do this in an ActiveRecord callback.

### Have the DB generate the key

An alternative solution would be to have your database generate the unique key on create. A function like the one described in this blogpost [A Better ID Generator For PostgreSQL](https://rob.conery.io/2014/05/28/a-better-id-generator-for-postgresql/) may serve your purpose better.

This solution has the advantage that your application code does not need to be concerned about generating or catching collisions. The drawback is though that this solution is DB specific.